# How can i position a drawable Resource file in Android

Tags: android, xml

I've created a Drawable Ressource File to use it as the background of a textview. However, i don't know how to properly position it, so that it is matching the Textviews position. Any Advice?

[image]

**My Activities xml File:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/annotationTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Drawable Rounded Corner:**

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />

<solid android:color="@color/kss_red" />

<size
    android:width="16dp"
    android:height="16dp"/>


<item android:left="-10dp"/>
```

Comment: Try to use android:gravity="centre" in your textview layout

Comment: Try to use a fixed width and height for your `TextView` (its recommended to use the same value while you want a circle as background) and add `android:gravity="center"` property to your `TextView`.

Comment: omg rami! android:gravity="center" did the trick!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:gravity="center"` property to your `TextView` to center the text:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/annotationTxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iconImg"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progress"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

And i recommend you to use a fixed `width` and `height` (same value) for your `TextView` instead of `wrap_content` to not stretch the circle in the background if you have a long text.

Answer (score 0):

For this, set your gravity to center than the image will be set to center position.

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

or check the gravity to center

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

try  `android:gravity="center"` on your textview